# Chrome renders <meter> values incorrectly when -webkit-appearance:rating-level-indicator

Tags: html, google-chrome

When I render this HTML/CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  <meter style="-webkit-appearance: rating-level-indicator;" min="1" max="5" value="5">5</meter>
</body>
```

Chrome 20.0.1132.57 only shows four stars. [You can see it in this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/bclennox/7KcfT/)

Am I misunderstanding how `<meter>` works, or is this a bug?

Comment: I am not seeing a problem in the same version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you're misunderstanding how it works. The minimum value represents "no stars", which in your case is a score of 1. I would assume that if you had `min="0"` then it would show the five stars.

Comment: You're right. It renders the delta between the `min` and the `value`, regardless of the `max`. Thanks!